# Where can I search by card for decks in major tournaments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Where I can search by card for decks from major modern tournaments? By major tournaments, I mean Grand Prixs, StarCityGames Open Series, TCGPlayer Max Point Series, and other large (200+) player tournaments.

For example, I need to be able to find modern decks that use a specific card. I have a [Tibalt, the Fiend-Blooded](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tibalt%2C%20the%20Fiend-Blooded) that I would like to find a use for (other than as a bookmark).

Comment: "Is Tibalt in any popular decks?" is a tricky question to answer because one poster could say "no, I've never seen anyone play it in my playgroup" and another could say "yes, i see it get used all the time in my playgroup" and they could both be right.

Comment: @Kevin While I agree it could probably be worded a little better I don't think 'popular' has the problem you are describing. Popular wouldn't mean 'I know this one guy that plays it' it is more 'It was played at X and Y tournaments in Z deck.

Comment: Ideally, OP would give us an objective definition of "popular" for this context. For example, if he defined it to mean "appeared in any deck that made the top 8 of a Modern pro tour qualifier", the answer would be fairly easy to find [here](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/ptq-top-8-decklists/khans-tarkir-top-8-modern-decklists-2014-06-19).

Comment: To those that are still down and close voting, notice that the question was extensively edited after the above comments were made. And then if you still want to downvote, go for it.

Comment: @Kevin Honestly I think it's fine even if it's not super super specific about what "popular" means; you could imagine data about top 8s, top 64s, day 2, the entire tournament... the OP (or future readers) might be interested in any data along these lines, and restricting the question too much runs the risk of excluding resources just because they don't happen to match the guess the OP made about a good criterion.

Comment: The question now has little relationship to the original. 'What are some top 8 decks that use /card/"  is vastly different than "What are some decks that use /card/". unless the card happens to be one that is used in top decks. The asker has specifically mentioned a card that is not a top card (hence the 'bookmark' comment), so this is now edited into something unrelated.  How Ye's answer is good for the current question, but is useless for the original.

Answer (score 5):

magic.tcgplayer.com allows you to search deck lists based on a particular card being used.  [Here's the search](http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/deck_search_result.asp?CardName=Tibalt,%20the%20Fiend-Blooded) for Tibalt.  You can also use their Deck search tools to limit by format and place finished in addition to specific cards.

Limiting your search to include decks using Tibalt, in the Modern format, that placed at least 1st through 64th returns zero results, indicating that no successful deck in the entire TCGPlayer database has ever used Tibalt.

Answer (score 2):

mtgtop8.com appears to collect some of the data you're interested in (top finishes at GPs, SCG events, MTGO, etc.). It has decks broken down by format and by archetype, so that you can see what trends in the meta-game.